# Free software for group video chat

Tags: software-rec, skype, instant-messaging, video-chat

Skype has recently started charging $10/month for group video chat, which neither me nor my friends wish to pay. Are there any *free*, cross-platform (Windows and OS X) applications which can do *video* chat between 3 or more people at once? Either a desktop application or a web application would work. When making recommendations, it would be helpful to state whether it's a desktop or web app, what features it has, and whether it requires sign-up for the service. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't $10/month only for OS X clients ?

Comment: @Sathya, according to [Skype's website](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/features/allfeatures/group-video-calls/), free group video calling is only available as a 28 day trial. Also, some of the people I need to use it with have only OS X or only Windows, so we need a solution which is free on both platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [ooVoo](http://www.oovoo.com)
- [TokBox](http://www.tokbox.com)

Comment: ooVoo won't work; they [charge a subscription](http://www.oovoo.com/Buy.aspx?pname=Plans) for 3+ person video calls.  Tokbox [VideoChat](http://me.tokbox.com/videochat) looks potentially promising though - I will give that a try, and report back on how that works

Comment: TokBox worked quite well, thanks for the tip. The quality isn't great, but it works, and it's nice not having to install any software locally (it runs in the browser as a flash app).

Answer (score 0):

[Google+ hangouts](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/?hl=en) is the only free tool I've been able to use – it's a webapp though.